# many to numerous connection amongst nations and hash table

Tags: database, database-design

Database design problem:

I have to model a situation where I have a table Hashtag (which contains hash_id, hashtag_name, count positive and count negative and other details of the hashtag) which has to be related to two different tables cities and country.

I further classified my problem we have a database schema in which we store hashtags just like twitter site, for example if someone upload status and uses hashtag #java so we search user city and country, means java hashtag uploaded by this user in Karachi and Karachi located in Pakistan so there are many to many relations between hashtag table and cities table and same many to many relations between hashtag table and country table and county table has one too many relations with cities.

so there is a problem - one hashtag come from many cities similarly one hashtag came from many countries. Can anyone help me to simplify this problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. A city only ever has one country (not considering border changes due to conflict, which may be something to consider when working on an international scale).
2. An individual instance of a hashtag can only ever originate from one city.
3. An individual instance of a hashtag is related to the collection of hashtags.

   ```
   Table: Hashtag
   HashtagID
   HashtagText

   Table: Country
   CountryID
   CountryName

   Table: City
   CityID
   CityName
   CountryID (FK to Country)

   Table: HashtagUsage
   HashtagID (FK to Hashtag)
   CityID (FK to City)
   DateTimeUsed
   ```

Every usage of a hashtag is related to only one hashtag and one city and has a timestamp of when it was used.

This is a very simplified model, but hopefully it will help you see the approach to modelling many-to-many relationships.

If your are modeling this for a date-warehouse, hashtag, city and country are dimensions, hashtagusage is the event(fact) table.

Comment: thank you for your answer but in this scenario, we handle many to many relationships but the main point is that we see the trend analysis of each country and city by using the hashtag, which means  if we have the same hashtag that doesn't need any entry its simply increments   in that hashtag column is that possible ?

Comment: This will handle a many to many relationship.  A hashtag can be used in many cities, a city can have many hashtags.  If you only increment the value, you'll run into problems if an error ever occurs.(Did it increment before or after the error?)